# Duplicate table in jooq with foreignkey and primary key

Tags: java, sql, jooq

i have a question, i duplicated a table with:

```
Table<?> table = DSL.table(DSL.name("dc2", "process"));
    dsl.createTable(table).as(dsl.select().from("dc1.process")).withNoData().execute();
```

but doesn't copy a primary key and foreignkey, how i do?

and if i want to duplicate schema in jooq?
thanks
Giuseppe

Comment: For the record, [this question was also asked on the jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/SYl99mMVkCY)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the code generator to produce your original schema, you can duplicate it relatively easily using:

- Runtime schema mapping: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping/
- [`DSLContext.ddl()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#ddl(org.jooq.Schema)) and/or [`Meta.ddl()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Meta.html#ddl())

A more convenient syntax will be supported in the future via standard SQL `CREATE TABLE (.. LIKE othertable)` syntax:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8860

Or a synthetic `CREATE SCHEMA .. LIKE otherschema` syntax:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9527